# Pass value from textbox to row in Grdicontrol in DevExpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Im using Gridcontrol and i want to add products to gidview and i use this code

```
Public Sub InsertBarcode()
        Dim x As Integer
        Try
            If Con.State = 1 Then Close()
            Con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from Products where ProdBarCode=@ProdBarCode", Con)
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdBarCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtBarcode.Text
            Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If dr.HasRows Then
                While dr.Read
                    GridView1.AddNewRow()
                    x = GridView1.RowCount - 1

                    GridView1.SetRowCellValue(x, GridView1.Columns(0), dr("ProdId").ToString)
                    GridView1.SetRowCellValue(x, GridView1.Columns(1), dr("ProdName").ToString)
                    GridView1.SetRowCellValue(x, GridView1.Columns(2), dr("QtyAvailabe").ToString)
                    GridView1.SetRowCellValue(x, GridView1.Columns(3), dr("BuyPrice").ToString)
                    GridView1.UpdateCurrentRow()
                End While
                dr.Close()
                Con.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("There is no data")
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            Con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

and this to call the method

```
Private Sub TxtBarcode_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles TxtBarcode.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        InsertBarcode()
        TxtBarcode.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

but when i add barcode there no data added to Row of gridview

Comment: Just an initial eyeballing, think you might want to look at the difference between cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue and cmd.Parameters.Add.  You might have mixed up to two methods their.  The Second param in AddWithValue is normally the Value where what you've got now looks more like the Add method

Answer (score 0):

First, you can replace the code for filling the gridview with this.

```
 Public Function ReturnDataTable(Query As String) As DataTable

Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim SQL_Adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
Dim SQL_DataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim SQL_Connection As New SqlConnection( Your Connection String Var or String )
SQL_Adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, SQL_Connection)
SQL_Adapter.Fill(dt) 
Return dt

End function
```

Now you can add in your code the below code

```
 Dim Query As String = " Your SELECT Query"
grid.datasource=ReturnDataTable(Query)
```

And Final Step Try to Use This Query:

```
"Select * from Products where ProdBarCode='" & TxtBarcode.Text & "'"
```